# How to change the SDK of a UWP .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, arm64

I am trying to build my C# app in ARM64 using Visual Studio. When I select ARM64 in the configuration to build, I run into the following error:

"The processor architecture of the project being built "ARM64" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.1". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM".

It looks like the SDK that I am using does not support ARM64, only ARM32. I am new to .NET applications and simply got this project from a github repo, I haven't even downloaded any SDKs. Is it possible for me to change the SDK to a version that supports ARM64? Is there something written in a configuration file in the code directory itself that automatically downloads .NET.CoreRuntime Version 1.1 for me when I tried to build/run this code?

Any clarity on the subject is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you need the sdk: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: Why is it that I did not need to download an SDK initially? Is it possible that Visual Studio downloaded the SDK for me? Or, is there a 'default' SDK per app located somewhere in a configuration file?

Comment: Run the app in X64 or X86 not arm64

Comment: That is not an option for me. I specifically need this app to be built in ARM64.

Comment: Could you please tell me what VS version you are using? Based on this document-[Troubleshooting Arm UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/apps-on-arm-troubleshooting-arm32), you will need to use  Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 or later, or Visual Studio 2019